# Amazon sp-API aws signature issue

Tags: signature, amazon-product-api

AMAZON SP-API AWS SIGNATURE The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details

```
    public function getOrdersFromApi(){
                // Configuration values
                $host                   = 'sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com';
                $accessKey              = 'XXXXX';
                $secretKey              = 'XXXXXX';
                $region                 = 'eu-west-1';
                $service                = 'execute-api';
    
                /**
                * You should modify the script
                * for
                *   1. full request url
                *   2. uri for AWS signature
                *   3. request method GET / POST / PUT
                *   4. actual data of the request
                * and call the above functions
                */
                $requestUrl = 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/orders/v0/orders?MarketplaceIds=A21TJRUUN4KGV&CreatedAfter=2021-01-15T05:26:31.308992';
                $uri = '?MarketplaceIds=A21TJRUUN4KGV&CreatedAfter=2021-01-15T05:26:31.308992';
                $httpRequestMethod = 'GET';
    
                $data = json_encode(array());
    
                $headers = $this->calcualteAwsSignatureAndReturnHeaders($host, $uri, $requestUrl, 
                            $accessKey, $secretKey, $region, $service, 
                            $httpRequestMethod, $data, TRUE);
    
                $result = $this->callToAPI($requestUrl, $httpRequestMethod, $headers, $data, TRUE);
    
                print_r($result);
    
        }


    public function calcualteAwsSignatureAndReturnHeaders($host, $uri, $requestUrl, 
                $accessKey, $secretKey, $region, $service, 
                $httpRequestMethod, $data, $debug = TRUE){
    
        $terminationString  = 'aws4_request';
        $algorithm      = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
        $phpAlgorithm       = 'sha256';
        $canonicalURI       = $uri;
        $canonicalQueryString   = '';
        $signedHeaders      = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date'; $signedHeaders = "content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token";
    
        $currentDateTime = new DateTime('UTC');
        $reqDate = $currentDateTime->format('Ymd');
        $reqDateTime = $currentDateTime->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
    
        // Create signing key
        $kSecret = $secretKey;
        $kDate = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $reqDate, 'AWS4' . $kSecret, true);
        $kRegion = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $region, $kDate, true);
        $kService = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $service, $kRegion, true);
        $kSigning = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $terminationString, $kService, true);
    
        // Create canonical headers
        $canonicalHeaders = array();
        $canonicalHeaders[] = 'content-type:application/json';
        $canonicalHeaders[] = 'host:' . $host;
        $canonicalHeaders[] = 'x-amz-date:' . $reqDateTime;
        $canonicalHeadersStr = implode("\n", $canonicalHeaders);
    
        // Create request payload
        $requestHasedPayload = hash($phpAlgorithm, $data);
    
        // Create canonical request
        $canonicalRequest = array();
        $canonicalRequest[] = $httpRequestMethod;
        $canonicalRequest[] = $canonicalURI;
        $canonicalRequest[] = $canonicalQueryString;
        $canonicalRequest[] = $canonicalHeadersStr . "\n";
        $canonicalRequest[] = $signedHeaders;
        $canonicalRequest[] = $requestHasedPayload;
        $requestCanonicalRequest = implode("\n", $canonicalRequest);
        $requestHasedCanonicalRequest = hash($phpAlgorithm, utf8_encode($requestCanonicalRequest));
        if($debug){
            echo "<h5>Canonical to string</h5>";
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $requestCanonicalRequest;
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    
        // Create scope
        $credentialScope = array();
        $credentialScope[] = $reqDate;
        $credentialScope[] = $region;
        $credentialScope[] = $service;
        $credentialScope[] = $terminationString;
        $credentialScopeStr = implode('/', $credentialScope);
    
        // Create string to signing
        $stringToSign = array();
        $stringToSign[] = $algorithm;
        $stringToSign[] = $reqDateTime;
        $stringToSign[] = $credentialScopeStr;
        $stringToSign[] = $requestHasedCanonicalRequest;
        $stringToSignStr = implode("\n", $stringToSign);
        if($debug){
            echo "<h5>String to Sign</h5>";
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $stringToSignStr;
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    
        // Create signature
        $signature = hash_hmac($phpAlgorithm, $stringToSignStr, $kSigning);
    
        // Create authorization header
        $authorizationHeader = array();
        $authorizationHeader[] = 'Credential=' . $accessKey . '/' . $credentialScopeStr;
        $authorizationHeader[] = 'SignedHeaders=' . $signedHeaders;
        $authorizationHeader[] = 'Signature=' . ($signature);
        $authorizationHeaderStr = $algorithm . ' ' . implode(', ', $authorizationHeader);
    
    
        // Request headers
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'authorization:'.$authorizationHeaderStr;
        $headers[] = 'content-length:'.strlen($data);
        $headers[] = 'content-type: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'user-agent:sellergeni/1.0 (Php=7.2)';
        $headers[] = 'x-amz-access-token:Atza|IwEBII0yZlQvoo95puL9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $headers[] = 'host: ' . $host;
        $headers[] = 'x-amz-date: ' . $reqDateTime;
    
        return $headers;
    }
    
    public  function callToAPI($requestUrl, $httpRequestMethod, $headers, $data, $debug=TRUE)
    {
        // Execute the call
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $requestUrl,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_POST => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $httpRequestMethod,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
          CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 0,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
          CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
          CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=>true,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        ));
    
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        $responseCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    
        if($debug){
            $headers = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
            echo "<h5>Request</h5>";
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $headers;
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    
        curl_close($curl);
    
        if ($err) {
            if($debug){
                echo "<h5>Error:" . $responseCode . "</h5>";
                echo "<pre>";
                echo $err;
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        } else {
            if($debug){
                echo "<h5>Response:" . $responseCode . "</h5>";
                echo "<pre>";
                echo $response;
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }
        
        return array(
            "responseCode" => $responseCode,
            "response" => $response,
            "error" => $err
        );
    }
```

```
 Response of this code  like this
    
    Canonical to string
    GET
    ?MarketplaceIds=A21TJRUUN4KGV&CreatedAfter=2021-01-15T05:26:31.308992
    
    content-type:application/json
    host:sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
    x-amz-date:20210204T060039Z
    
    content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token
    4f53cda18c2baa0c0354bb5f9a3ecbe5ed12ab4d8e11ba873c2f11161202b945
    String to Sign
    AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
    20210204T060039Z
    20210204/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request
    f11a59afb96cf62bbdd17e44405da8c5567178531f839826e89e9b1fcb77a24a
    Request
    GET /orders/v0/orders?MarketplaceIds=A21TJRUUN4KGV&CreatedAfter=2021-01-15T05:26:31.308992 HTTP/1.1
    Host: sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
    Accept: */*
    authorization:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/20210204/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=3ddc540c9a1e38ea0466e4d4570a5ea8a1bc7274cfbc2fffd50609c7f379c495
    content-length:2
    content-type: application/json
    user-agent:sellergeni/1.0 (Php=7.2)
    x-amz-access-token:Atza|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    x-amz-date: 20210204T060039Z
    
    Response:403
    {
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    
    The Canonical String for this request should have been
    'GET
    /orders/v0/orders
    CreatedAfter=2021-01-15T05%3A26%3A31.308992&MarketplaceIds=A21TJRUUN4KGV
    content-type:application/json
    host:sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com
    user-agent:sellergeni/1.0 (Php=7.2)
    x-amz-access-token:Atza|IwEBII0yZlQvoo95puL9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    x-amz-date:20210204T060039Z
    x-amz-security-token:
    
    content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token
    4f53cda18c2baa0c0354bb5f9a3ecbe5ed12ab4d8e11ba873c2f11161202b945'
    
    The String-to-Sign should have been
    'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
    20210204T060039Z
    20210204/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request
    e995c02098c1a2d5d775380f1fc49804b32af9534b5e330145ca125fe098f0af'
    ",
         "code": "InvalidSignature"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sign pathparam/resource
```

Replace:

```
/messaging/v1/orders/{orderId}
```

with:

```
/messaging/v1/orders/xxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx
```

Comment: Hi Jack, I do not see any "/messaging/v1/order" in the question above. Can you kindly advise? Thank you very much!